# reverse function: from output to input

Tags: vb.net, reflection.emit

there is a simple function that from a configuration file, with its value, return a byte array and then the following functions write it on Data Memory on a PLC.
Here is my question: i need to read firt of all these data Memory, get its values, and check if is there any different value with my configuration file's values.

Then from this byte array, write the corrispondentig values on the configuration file; in other word i need a reverse function that from output returns the input.

I think it is a very usefull function.
Maybe using reflection??

Thanks for any help
Matteo M.

Comment: I can't make any sense of this question I'm afriad

Comment: i try to give you a better, short explanation. Anyone knows if there is a method to get the input values (parameters) from a returned value (return value of a function)? I know that with reflection i can do almost anything... My need is no reverse each function bymyself, but using any other help functions.

Comment: Do you have the source code for this function?

Comment: I can give you any function, my need is to no reverse manually these functions...

Comment: Imagine a function that multiplies to numbers together and returns that value? You can't find the twose numbers from the result - even with reflection.

Comment: the "direct" function is known; a sample simple "direct" fuction is an assignation like... Parameters(Id).Value(1) = .Var1; the "reverse" function sound like this... .Var1 = Parameters(Id).Value(1)... is there any method to get the reverse with no manually write it?

Comment: That is not much clearer I'm afriad

Comment: If I understand your question, then I don't believe it is possible. You would need to create your own function to write the new byte array back to the configuration file.

Comment: thanks topshot, this is the "much clearer" answer that was written in this post.